# How to put the checkbox at the bottom of the div?

Tags: html, css, checkbox

[image]

[image]

this is my code

```
                       <div class="blanline2">
                            <input type="checkbox" name="car" />
                            <label id="low_login" class="low_login">下次自动登录</label>
                        </div>
   .blanline2 {
    width: 280px;
    height:40px;

  }
```

Below, I think will be the first figure into the second figure style

Who can help I will grateful for you

Comment: where is your code ?

Comment: Can you show us your CSS also ?

Comment: @nicholas can you see my code ?you can help me.

Comment: Put your wording in <input type="checkbox" name="car">Your label</input> then it will be [Box] [Text]
http://jsfiddle.net/4jyaypv1/8/ Here 2 example

Answer (score 1):

HTML

```
<div class="blanline2">
   <input type="checkbox" name="car" />   
   <label id="low_login" class="low_login">下次自动登录</label>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.blanline2 { display: flex; }
```

DEMO: http://jsfiddle.net/wxocofu6/3/

Answer (score 1):

I'm kinda confused about what you want exactly, so I did two of them. The CSS applies only to Example 2, Example 1 didn't need any CSS.

```css
.blanline3,
.blanline2 {
  width: 200px;
  height: 40px;
}
.low_login2 {
  display: block;
  text-align: center;
}
input[name='car2'],
input[name='car3'] {
  margin-left: 45%;
}
```

```html
<p>EXAMPLE 1 - Just HTML no Extra CSS</p>

<div class="blanline2">
  <label id="low_login" class="low_login">
    <input type="checkbox" name="car" />下次自动登录
  </label>
</div>

<p>EXAMPLE 2 - Checkbox Under the Label</p>

<div class="blanline3">
  <label id="low_login2" class="low_login2">
    下次自动登录
  </label>
  <input type="checkbox" name="car2" />
</div>

<p>EXAMPLE 3 - Combined</p>

<div class="blanline3">
  <input type="checkbox" name="car3" />
  <label id="low_login2" class="low_login2">

    下次自动登录</label>
  <input type="checkbox" name="car2" />
</div>

<p>EXAMPLE 4 - Combined 2</p>


<div class="blanline3">
  <input type="checkbox" name="car4" />
  <label id="low_login2" class="low_login4">
    下次自动登录
  </label>
  <input type="checkbox" name="car2" />
</div>
```

Comment: Updated, did you want both types? Left checkbox and checkbox below the label?

Comment: @wanghao That's all I can make out of guessing what you are saying. Good luck to you, sir.

Answer (score 0):

Its best to include your full code with css and html preferably with a codepen or jsfiddle

But from what i can see all you would need to do is add

```
.blanline2{
 position:relative;
}
```

and

```
.blanline2 input{
 position:absolute;
 bottom:0;
}
```